# How to change image PPI in batch mode?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

Is it possible to change an image resolution expressed in [pixels per inch (PPI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density) in batch mode, using command line?

My images resolution is currently below 100 PPI.
I would like to enhance it to 300 PPI.
I am preparing a document for self publish.
The agency says that the images PPI should be 300.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Hello and welcome to Ubuntu.SE!

## Here is a proposal using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org)

You can use ImageMagick for that task:
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php

## Example

Here is a `40x30` pixels original image (file size of `1367 bytes`) with a resolution of `72 PPI` (in both `X` and `Y` directions):

[image: original image]

You can change its resolution using the following command:

```
convert -units PixelsPerInch my_original_image.jpg -density 300 my_new_image.jpg
```

This is the result of the previous command:

[image: Changed PPI with density]

`X Resolution 300 PPI`
`Y Resolution 300 PPI`
`Image Size 40x30 pixels`
`File Size 981 bytes`

Or if you need resampling:

```
convert -units PixelsPerInch my_original_image.jpg -resample 300 my_new_image.jpg
```

Which gives:

[image: Changed PPI with resample]

`X Resolution 300 PPI`
`Y Resolution 300 PPI`
`Image Size 167x125 px`
`File Size 7.7 kB`

Don't hesitate to open these images with [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org) for example to see the differences.

---

#### Source

https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=18241

#### More information

https://medium.com/@onlinelogomaker/what-is-the-difference-between-dpi-ppi-resolution-and-image-size-b42328e7ed22
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_resolution